# Alternative for IPhone Configuration Utility in Ubuntu?

Tags: ios, iphone, ubuntu, console, error-log

Can Anyone tell me what is the the alternative for IPhone Configuration Utility in ubuntu. i want to see my console logs for development . it was very easy in windows or mac but ubuntu is driving me crazy. Help will be appreciated

Answer (score -4):

I have not used Ubuntu OS yet. But following is the another way to see device logs that might help you please check:

Steps :

1) Connect device to machine.

2) Go to Xcode - Select "Window" menu from top bar select "Organizer" then select "Devices" (extreme left option present on Organizer window).

3) At left side pane under "DEVICES" section select the connected device. Expand it by clicking on drop down arrow which is present before the device name. Select device logs then check middle pane select one to show details log which is in right side pane.

Comment: Ubuntu is not Mac OS X.